# Unable to access a NodePort service on Minikube

Tags: minikube

I have minikube running. Minikube status results into:

```
kubectl: Correctly Configured: pointing to minikube-vm at 192.168.99.100
```

And I defined a Service, with the following port configuration:

```
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8082
      targetPort: 8082
      nodePort: 30082
```

But when I try to access the service on the following URLs, it is not reachable:

```
http://192.168.99.100:30082
http://192.168.99.100:8082
```

Is it a must to have an Ingress defined in addition? Could I do without an Ingress? Which port?

Thanks - Christian

Below the full yaml of the service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    description: LAC 51 Service
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{"description":"LAC 51 Service"},"labels":{"name":"lac51","service":"lac51-svc"},"name":"lac51-svc","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"ports":[{"name":"lac51-http-port","nodePort":30082,"port":8082,"protocol":"TCP","targetPort":8082}],"selector":{"app":"lac51"},"type":"NodePort"}}
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    name: lac51
    service: lac51-svc
  name: lac51-svc
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/services/lac51-svc
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - name: lac51-http-port
    port: 8082
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8082
  selector:
    app: lac51
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: NodePort
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Answer (score 11):

It seems that is related to the default `docker` driver used when you start the `minikube`.
To avoid these problems you can force a specific driver (e.g. "virtualbox"). To do so, follow the next steps:

1. Remove old minikube with:

```sh
    minikube delete
```

2. Start minikube with virtualbox driver:

```sh
minikube start --memory=4096 --driver=virtualbox
```

3. Run `minikube ip`. You'll see an output like `192.168.99.100`.
4. Then, create again the Pods and the service and it should work properly.

I've found this info in this issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/7344#issuecomment-703225254

Comment: This was the issue for me as well ... --driver=hyperkit worked for me as well -- so ... what's the default driver on mac?
BTW, to set the driver permanently, folks may want to `minikube config set driver xxx`.

Comment: this solution worked for me in`mac os`

Answer (score 7):

In this case ingress is not necessary, Minikube should expose the service by itself. However if you want to give it a try here's a [tutorial](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/).

You can run `minikube service list` to get list of all available services with their corresponding URL's. Also make sure the service points to correct pod by using correct `selector`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ... I can obtain the URL of the service but when I try to cUrl into it I have a connection refused (all is running locally on my machine): $ minikube service lac51-svc --url
http://192.168.99.100:30082
$ curl -v http://192.168.99.100:30082
*   Trying 192.168.99.100...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connection failed
* connect to 192.168.99.100 port 30082 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 192.168.99.100 port 30082: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.99.100 port 30082: Connection refused

Comment: Can you post whole YAML of the service? You can use `kubectl get svc <service_name> -o yaml --export=true`

Comment: Thanks - just added it at the back of my initial post.

Answer (score 5):

if you are using a Docker drive on linux, you need terminal this code to forward a port.

```
minikube service serviceName --url
or
minikube service --all
```

then you can curl minikube url to connect your service

Answer (score 3):

for m1 users, when starting minikube run this command

```
minikube start --ports=<port-target>:<node-port>
```

for eg;

```
minikube start --ports=30000:30000
```

and for exposing multiple ports, separate them by comma, eg;

```
minikube start --ports=30000:30000,32000:32000
```

and now you access the pod via:
**http://localhost:30000**

Comment: What was your host and driver, do you remember? I'm having hard time getting it to work with docker on Ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to go through the "virutalbox" route, then "port-forwarding" is an additional step you may need , like so :

`kubectl port-forward <podname> <hostport>:<podport> -n <namespace-name>`

podport: output from: `kubectl get pod <podname> --template='{{(index (index .spec.containers 0).ports 0).containerPort}}{{"\n"}}' -n <namespace-name>`

hostport: your desired port , say port 8080.

once forwarding starts then `http://localhost:8080` on your browser should load your app.

For Mac OS users , [hyperkit](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/hyperkit/) should do the job , like

```
minikube start --driver=hyperkit
```

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS has networking limitations, `--vm=true` downloads VM image: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/7332

```
minikube stop
minikube delete
minikube start --vm=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Run command

> minikube service serviceName

, It will open a tunnel and link will be opened in default browser.

Answer (score 0):

To add to [xserrat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64323976/10907864)

I faced this issue when using the Docker driver for Minikube in MacOS.

However, when I try to increase the capacity of the cluster using the commands below:

```
minikube stop
minikube delete
minikube start --memory=4096 --cpus=2
```

I get the error:

> ❌  Exiting due to MK_USAGE: Docker Desktop has only 1985MB memory but you specified 4096MB

All I had to do was to try another driver like the 'virtualbox` driver:

```
minikube stop
minikube delete
minikube start --memory=4096 --cpus=2 --driver=virtualbox
```

**Reference**: [Minikube: Start With More Memory & CPUs](https://www.shellhacks.com/minikube-start-with-more-memory-cpus/)